# How to feed array of user_ids to flickr.people.getInfo()?

Tags: python, api, pandas, numpy, flickr

I have been working on extracting the flickr users location (not lat. and long. but person's country) by using their user_ids. I have made a dataframe [(Here's the dataframe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY6jF.png) consisted with photo id, owner  and few other columns. My attempt was to feed each of the owner to `flickr.people.getInfo()` query by iterating owner column in dataframe. Here is my attempt

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     A=np.array(df["owner"])
for i in range(len(A)):
    B=flickr.people.getInfo(user_id=A[i])
```

unfortunately, it results only 1 result. After careful examination I've found that it belongs to the last user in the dataframe. My dataframe has 250 observations. I don't know how could I extract others.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to store the results while iterating over the dataframe. I haven't use the API but I think that this snippet should do it.

```py
result_dict = {}
for idx, owner in df['owner'].iteritems():
    result_dict[owner] = flickr.people.getInfo(user_id=owner)
```

The results are stored in a dictonary where the user id is the key.

EDIT:

Since it is a JSON you can use the [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function to parse the result.
Example:

```py
result_list = []
for idx, owner in df['owner'].iteritems():
    result_list.appen(pd.read_json(json.dumps(flickr.people.get‌​Info(user_id=owner))‌​,orient=list))
    # you may have to set the orient parameter. 
    # Option are: 'split','records','index', Default is 'index'
```

*Note: I switched the dictonary to a list, since it is more convenient*

Afterwards you can concatenate the resulting pandas serieses together like this:

```py
df = pd.concat(result_list, axis=1).transpose()
```

I added the `transpose()` since you probably want the ID as the index.
Afterwards you should be able to sort by the column 'location'.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ey Jay, your solution works, but I ended up with big json file. Bit struggling to separate location for each user and convert it to DF. I couldn't find a way to iterate the dictionary for all users and respective locations. I have done one indexing as follows, `result_dict['117692977@N08']["person"]["location"]['_content']` which results location. But I couldn't find a way to iterate all owners in dictonary. Would be greatful if you have time to go through as I am bit novice to python.

Comment: Hey EyJay, thanks for your input, I have done it nicely with this time with python list. However, I have edit one line of your code as follows. `result_list.append(pd.read_json(json.dumps(flickr.people.getInfo(user_id=owner)),orient=list))`, this would help to achieve it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to achieve that is to use an `apply`. It will be much more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

# A function to simulate the call to the API
def get_user_info(id):
    return np.random.randint(id, id + 10)

# Some test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2], 'name': ['Pierre', 'Paul', 'Jacques']})

# Here the call is made for each ID
df['info'] = df['id'].apply(get_user_info)

#    id     name  info
# 0   0   Pierre     5
# 1   1     Paul     1
# 2   2  Jacques     5
```

Note, another way to write the same thing is

```
df['info'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: get_user_info(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the method, have the following lines first.

```
from flickrapi import FlickrAPI

flickr = FlickrAPI(FLICKR_KEY, FLICKR_SECRET, format='parsed-json')
```